# FreeRTOS | Passing user entered character to a task

Tags: c, embedded, task, esp32, freertos

I was working on the ESP-32 with FreeRTOS, What I was trying to achieve is , I want to pass the character entered by the user to a task.. And the following piece of code is what I have written and which is not working as expected,

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <freertos/FreeRTOS.h>
#include <freertos/task.h>

void task(void* pvParameters){
  char* data;
  data = (char *) pvParameters;
  while (true)
  {
    printf("%s\n", data);
    vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
}

void app_main(void){
  
  char c = 0;
  char * data = "Hello";
  while (c != '\n')
  {
    c = getchar();
    if(c != 0xff){
      data = &c ;
      printf(" The entered %c\n", c);
      printf(" The data entered %c\n", *data);
    }
    vTaskDelay(100/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
  }
  xTaskCreate(task, "task1", 4096, (void*) data, 1, NULL);
}
```

---

What is the mistake I am making here.

Comment: The question cannot be answered here in a short port. You need to learn about multitasking programming. Learn about the queuesm semaphores, mutexes etc. At the moment (judging from the code) you did not even read the freeRtos documentation.

Comment: I started reading it , But in the xTaskCreate(), pg;58 of mastering the freeRtos, They are passing a static const char , Similar way I tried to implement this , but failed . I am sorry , but can you tell me what I should read on for this.?

Answer (score 1):

For example usuing queues:

In the task you wait for the queue. In the user interface task you post the queue.

BTW your code is wrong in many other ways. Is full of UBs. I would advice to start from the C book, then learn how communication between task should be done and eventually to start with freeRTOS.

Comment: But @P__J__, I am sorry but , still I want to achieve something like this as I have written , I will wait till the user press "enter", and the last entered character is need to be passed to the task. For that  only I wrote the while loop and I want that character to be printing in every 2 sec.

Comment: Is it not possible to implement something like this in the way I thought .

Comment: What you have written is wrong. It is not the way how the IPC works. Sorry.

Comment: @AjitJoseph no. it is not possible. Your code does not make any sense

Comment: Ok , Thanks for the advice . I will read on the Inter-Processor-Communication. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is app_main() a task?  If not you cannot call vTaskDelay() in it as the scheduler is not running there is nothing to delay.

Are you just trying to pass a stream of input characters to a task?  If so then a stream buffer might be the most appropriate https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-stream-buffer-example.html

On the other hand, you might just be trying to pass one set of data to the task when the task is created?

Comment: I am trying to send just one character which the user entered just before pressing “enter” key.